# Will a Fortran container class automatically call a contained object's destructor?

Tags: oop, fortran, destructor

Suppose I have the following box class which holds some glasses:

```
TYPE :: box_class
   TYPE(glass_class) :: cup1
   TYPE(glass_class) :: cup2
END TYPE
```

where the glass class has a destructor:

```
TYPE:: glass_class
  CONTAINS
   FINAL :: glass_destructor
END TYPE
```

When my `box` object goes out of scope will that automatically call the `glass_destructor` or do I need to call the `glass_destructor` manually in a `box` destructor?

Answer (score 4):

The derived type `glass_class` is finalizable because it has a final subroutine.  The derived type `box_class` is finalizable even without a final subroutine because of the finalizable components (non-pointer and non-allocatable).

Now, when an object of `type(box_class)` is finalized we follow the finalization process (F2008, 4.5.6.2):

- no subroutine is called to finalize the box object;
- the final subroutines for the cups are called, in some processor-dependent order;
- no parent final subroutine exists.

In summary: yes, if your box is to be finalized then the cups will be finalized through that.  You needn't do more to make that explicit.

Answer (score 2):

That is the whole point of finalization, that it is automatic. Yes, they will be called, because they go out of scope the same way as the parent final procedure is called when it goes out of scope.

You may need an explicit deallocate if you have a pointer component but even then the final procedure will be automatically called with the deallocation.